# How do I add a deck of cards to an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, playing-cards

I am stuck on a project where I have to add a deck of cards to an array, we can't use a class and just have to use a method but I am stuck on how to go about this. The deck of cards will be used to compare the values like the card game "war"

so if Player 1 gets 5 of spades and the computer gets 2 of spades itll say

player 1 got the 5 of spades
player 2 got the 2 of spades
player 1 wins

wondering if anyone can just guide me in the right direction on where to begin

Comment: This would be long to explain, but I've created a simple Guide below, that would give you an idea of what to do next... I didn't include everything but I've left clues.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this, as a setup:

Define all card types:

```
var carTypes = new List<string>() 
{
  "Spades", "Diamonds", "Heads", "Clubs"
}
```

Now define card names and and their values as `enum`

```
enum cards
{
  Ace = 1, Two = 2, Three = 3, Four = 4, Five = 5, Six = 6, 
  Seven = 7, Either = 8, Nine = 9, Ten = 10, Jack = 11, Queen = 12, King = 13
}
```

Define a card structure:

```
class Card
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Type {get; set;
  public int value{ get; set; }
}
```

From here on you're set. All you need to do is to declare a Deck and put all your cards in there...

Let's define a Deck...

```
List<Card> deck = new List<Card>();
```

Let's fill up our Deck with the cards in order... We'll shuffle them later.

```
var cardsValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(cards));
for(int c = 0; c < cardValues.Count(); c++)
{
  // create each card of 4 different types
  foreach(var cardType in cardTypes)
  {
    deck.add(new Card{
       Name =  Enum.GetName(typeof(cards), c),
       Type = cardType,
       Value = cardsValues[c]
    });
  }
}
```

I will leave it here, Here's the next steps:

At this point, our stack is full of cards but they are all aligned in order by their value.  The following steps are to follow

- Shuffle the cards in the deck using `Random()` generator using `[0, deck.Count()]` as your Random generation Range... also try to ensure that each number generated is not repeated... So generate Random numbers `deck.Count()` times.
- Crate Player Class

```
 class Player{
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public bool is activePlayer { get; set; }
   public List<Card> StartCards { get; set;} // Stores Initial Cards.
   public List<Card> CardsPlayed { get; set; };
   public List<Card> CardsWon { get; set; };

   //... add methods that manipulate these arrays as the player plays
 }
```

- Now create your game with two players and a new array `List<Card> PlayedCards` that stores cards played on the ground and  Split the `deck` half for each player.. so each player is to receive `deck.Count() / 2` which is 26 cards.
- Create a logic class that is used to toggle through each player and call Player methods to manipulate their cards as they play...

Comment: Ohkay thank you!! I think I understand this, the teacher said we aren't able to uses classes due to use not reaching that point in the chapter but ill ask her if we can try and give this a shot! Thank You!!

Comment: Cool, Good luck with Everything! :) What a fun game that is. I actually enjoyed writing this answer..

Answer (score 1):

You said you can't use a class, which I would highly recommend, but if you can't, then just use an int for the card (0-51).

```
// initialize the decks
var rand = new Random();
var deck = Enumerable.Range(0,52)
  .Select(z=> new {num = z, order = rand.Next()} )
  .OrderBy(z=>z.order)
  .Select(z=>z.num)
  .ToArray();

var hand1 = deck.Take(26);
var hand2 = deck.Skip(26);
```

Then if you want your method to compare...

```
var faces = new [] {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
var suit = new [] {"Spades", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs"};
var result = $"Player 1 has a {faces[card1/4]} of {suit[card1 % 4]} " +
             $"Player 2 has a {faces[card2/4]} of {suit[card2 % 4]} ";

if (card1 / 4 == card2 / 4)
{
  result += "War!";
} else if (card1 < card2)
{
  result += "Player 2 wins";
} else {
  result += "Player 1 wins";
```

Comment: Note that I did not implement the actual war sequence.  You will have to loop or recurse to handle that.  And you will likely have to handle the discard piles as well, and add the appropriate cards to each players discard pile for reuse (and shuffle) when they run out of cards in their main pile.  While this code is extremely efficient (memory/cpu), I would never recommend this (anymore.. maybe 35 years ago).  Use a class, and keep the code maintainable.

Comment: Ok thank you!! i tried using this and triex using the enum but keep getting an error is there anything i have to declare? like using System.Generics; or anything?

Comment: Yes.  You will likely need System.Collections.Generic, and System.Linq.  If you list the error, it'd help.